# How to convert datetime.date into other format in python

Tags: python, datetime

I am getting the data in this format.

```
{datetime.date(2020, 6, 25)}
```

Is there any quick way to convert above into **2020-06-25**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import datetime    
print(datetime.date(2020, 6, 25).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

- `%Y` - year
- `%m` - month
- `%d` - day

Output:

```
'2020-06-25'
```

`{datetime.date(2020, 6, 25)}` - python considers this as a set. Instead you should apply the `strftime` on the datetime object inside the set i.e
`datetime.date(2020, 6, 25)`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It gives me this error: AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: I got you. But the response from API is set only.

Comment: Then use this - `{datetime.date(2020, 6, 25)}.pop().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`